# [XAI for transformer custom model using AllenNLP]

Tags: huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, allennlp

I have been solving the NER problem for a Vietnamese dataset with 15 tags in IO format. I have been using the AllenNLP Interpret Toolkit for my model, but I can not configure it completely.

I have used a pre-trained language model "xlm-roberta-base" based-on HuggingFace. I have concatenated 4 last bert layers, and pass through to linear layer. The model architecture you can see in the source below.

```
class BaseBertSoftmax(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model, drop_out , num_labels):
        super(BaseBertSoftmax, self).__init__()
        self.num_labels = num_labels
        self.model = model
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(drop_out)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(4*768, num_labels) # 4 last of layer
            
    def forward_custom(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None,
                        labels=None, head_mask=None):
        outputs = self.model(input_ids = input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        sequence_output = torch.cat((outputs[1][-1], outputs[1][-2], outputs[1][-3], outputs[1][-4]),-1)
        sequence_output = self.dropout(sequence_output)
            
        logits = self.classifier(sequence_output) # bsz, seq_len, num_labels
        outputs = (logits,) + outputs[2:]  # add hidden states and attention if they are here
        if labels is not None:
            loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=0)
            if attention_mask is not None:
                active_loss = attention_mask.view(-1) == 1
                active_logits = logits.view(-1, self.num_labels)[active_loss]
                active_labels = labels.view(-1)[active_loss]
                loss = loss_fct(active_logits, active_labels)
            else:
                    loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
            outputs = (loss,) + outputs
        return outputs  #scores, (hidden_states), (attentions)
```

What steps do I have to take to integrate this model to AllenNLP Interpret?
Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: There is a chapter in the guide about the interpret module: https://guide.allennlp.org/interpret

Comment: yeah, but my file weight is .pt, and I don't have no idea about tar.gz file, how I can change format from weight.pt to tar.gz and how I can config for my pre_trained language model (xlm-roberta) in config.json file.

Comment: I'll follow up on GitHub.